# Considering outliers in demand predictions

Tags: predictive-modeling, prediction, outlier

I have times series data with demand observations during months. I was wondering if, when computing demand predictions, I need to consider the outliers of the observations or not. What is your opinion on this?

**Edit:**

Here is my data:

```
month   demand
1       450
2       670
3       332
4       123
5       343
6       437
7       456
8        -
9       231
```

I would like to predict the demand for the 10th month. I have computed the value `670` as outlier (after having removed the 8th observation). I really don't know what I have to do with this outlier: should I consider it?

Comment: You probably should.

Comment: Is this the entire data available? If yes than probably any prediction more sophisticated than an average of last X month or simply the last month will have a hard time. If you want to remove outliers the 4th month is as suspicious as the 2nd...

Comment: Also: Do you have more input variables than this one?

Comment: Yes this is the only series I have

Comment: If this is all of your data, I don't really see how you can remove it.  You have 9 data points and want to remove 1, and then make a prediction?  At most, you could maybe infer seasonality.  If you have hundreds of these sequences, then use a seasonal anomaly detection method to remove outliers (such as Twitters method.)

Answer (score 0):

That depends ;). Without seeing the data I would say its very hard to say. It could be for example that you have the same demand every month but on December due to Christmas it is double. In this case just excluding the outlier would lead to loss of important information. Maybe you can expand your case/ show some data.

**EDIT:** Given the extreme limitations I personally would not give any forecasts. If you have to: Stick with some very naive approach as I can not imagine anything sophisticated will perform better. You can find a nice tutorial here: http://machinelearningmastery.com/simple-time-series-forecasting-models/

Regarding the outlier question: If you have a strong reason from the outside to exclude a certain month (for example you know that in a certain month something exceptional happened which had a clear impact on the demand) you can exclude this month.

Comment: That is not an outlier, that is a seasonal effect

Comment: I would say it can be both- outliers do not need to happen without reason.

Comment: Added data to my question :)